# upload multiple file with struts 1

Tags: file-upload, struts-1

i need to upload multiple files to the server .
i wrote the following code 
jsp :

```
<form action="fileUpload.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input type="file" name="image" />
  <input type="file" name="image" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">  
    </form>
```

ActionForm :

```
public class UploadForm extends ActionForm {

private FormFile[] image = new FormFile[2] ;


public FormFile[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(FormFile[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

it gives me this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Comment: Is it not safer to program, having `name=image0` and `name=image1`?

Comment: i didn't get what do you mean?

Comment: You are introducing a special case of array of files. Better a FormFile image0 and image1. (Struts long forgotten.) If you can make it for one FormFile, a second should be simple.

Comment: i already did it for one formfile , but in this case, the number of files may be unkown

Comment: In similar case I stupidly generated in a for-loop HTML for 10 inputs `image0` - `image9`. It is a feasible way, one needs to check whether there is a file. Not beautiful, so let's wait for a struts solution.

Comment: yes , but how to do in the ActionForm level , setters, and getters?

Comment: IIRC you'd need to have the file fields be indexed.

Comment: @DaveNewton i think this may be done with , the html:file , but i this case file inputs may be added via javascript

Comment: @fatiDev *How* they're rendered onto the page isn't relevant; that's all the S1 tags do, is render HTML. As long as the HTML you render for each new file field matches the expected naming conventions, it's not an issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton you proposition solved it

Answer (score 1):

You need use use similar form with input name="upload"

```
<form action="fileUpload.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="upload" />
   <input type="file" name="upload" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit">  
</form>
```

and on bean side you need

```
public class UploadBean extends BaseBean implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    protected ArrayList<FormFile> uploaded = new ArrayList<>(); 


    public void setUpload(List<FormFile> file) { uploaded.addAll(file); }

    public List<FormFile> getUpload() { return uploaded; }
}
```